# Android: adjustPan not working some times

Tags: android, adjustpan

I use this code :

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

But some times not work and on some device not work never